# Prometheus Api Count of Metric for one day

Tags: go, prometheus

Prometheus has `echo_requests_total{code="200",host="localhost:8080",method="POST",url="/"} 3`
metric.  It counts requests while app is running. However I want to get count of requests for one day. For example after 7 day  metric can be 5000 requests but I just want to get count of requests which sent today. I tried to find prometheus querying functions but I couldn't.

Comment: Have you tried to use`increase` function?